# Droid Explorer wont change anything (Delete, Paste, Uninstall)

Tags: uninstallation, files, delete, system-apps, copy-paste

I want change files in root but I can't.  It can't delete any system file (No change).
In addition it can't add any file in `system/app` or anywhere in root!

It can't uninstall any system app from `system/app`. (Droid Explorer Stopped working).
It can't update any system app like secCalculator2. (Droid Explorer Stopped working).

How can I change files from the PC not with an app in my phone.

---

device: Note Edge Rooted (deodexed Samy Rom) - Android: 5.1.1 - Kernel: Stock (permissive with busybox)

---

Answer (score 0):

You have to mount the */system* folder as *r/w*. To do this, execute:

```
adb shell 
su
mount -o remount,rw /system
```

Now you can modify your files.